# Update Sharepoint list using excel

Tags: list, excel

I have a SharePoint that has list and I need to be able to update this list with new values from an Excel sheet (using VBA).

This can be done from Access not a problem however I need it to be Excel only.

Is what I am asking possible and if some could point me in the direction of a solution.

Comment: Hi @Chris-Crew I have a very thorough and tested solution for just what you're looking for (but without VBA) on a related question.
**Answer**: [Import/Copy/Paste Data from Excel into Existing SharePoint List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/224375/44163).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check last section of below page:

http://flylib.com/books/en/3.464.1.67/1/

To import list from SharePoint:

```
Sub ImportListFromSP()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    Dim src(1) As Variant
    src(0) = "http://SharePointSiteAddress/_vti_bin"
    src(1) = "89F90972-FD90-4B04-BCEB-81840A82DA5E"

    ws.ListObjects.Add xlSrcExternal, src, True, xlYes, ws.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

To update modifications in SharePoint list:

```
Sub UpdateSPList()

   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim objListObj As ListObject

   Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
   Set objListObj = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

   objListObj.UpdateChanges xlListConflictDialog

End Sub
```

Comment: There's no `UpdateChanges` method in the `ListObject` in my Excel 2010. If fails with an error 1004: "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

Answer (score 7):

You can synchronize Excel 2007/2010 and SharePoint 2007/2010 with a download and install of a [Microsoft Excel Addin](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9345).

Here are some articles that has detailed description on how this is done -
[Excel to SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462636%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [SharePoint to Excel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/134054/Restoring-Two-Way-Synchronization-on-SharePoint-Lo)

Comment: This is one the that worked however few minute after finding solution it wasn't needed due to SQL server that no one knew about can be used.

Comment: Link `Excel to SharePoint` now redirects to a generic page. Thanks, Microsoft. That really helps.

Comment: I believe the Excel to SharePoint link originally pointed to what is now this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462636%28v=office.11%29.aspx In case that link goes down, perhaps it might be Googlable via "Publishing and Synchronizing Excel 2007 Tables to SharePoint Lists"

Comment: Looks like this Excel add-in is no longer available. What's the recommended way to sync Excel data to SharePoint now?

Answer (score 6):

Or you can use Sharepoint list synchronizer that will do that for you in a single click: [SharePoint List Synchronizer](http://www.synchronizer-for-excel-and-sharepoint.com)
I think there is a free version that you can try out.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to create a new list based on an Excel-Sheet, but you cannot update an existing list with Excel.

To save an Excel sheet to a list, click Site Actions->More options->Import Spreadsheet
[image: Import Spreadsheet]

Comment: I am aware of this option, creating the list is not the problem it is having the ability to update/change it

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways:

1. Excel Services - direclty on site - requires Enterprise license
2. Excel PowerPivot (FREE AddOn) supports REST which would enable connection to data and edit data directly see here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/powerpivot.aspx
3. Business Connectivity Services - connect to a lot of types of data (SQL Databases, Excel & CSV files, etc.) and provide real-time data access

Answer (score 0):

This has to be done by code if update/add the list items using the excel. I use the custom workflow action to update the list items from excel file, the excel file which store the list info and all items. So first upload the excel file to the document library then run the workflow to update/Add the item in excel to list. The workflow action will read the data from the excel then copy to the list items. You could write Convert class to convert the data to corresponding SharePoint field data. Then make the copy. The happiest thing that it could also run in sandbox solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done same thing using Excel Addin 2013. You can do the same using Addin by writing code of CSOM for SharePoint List. You can use this Event in Addin :

```
void Application_WorkbookBeforeSave(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Wb, bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
```

And In this event you can add code like following of mine :

```
try
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext clientContextproj = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("sharepointURL");
            Web siteproj = clientContextproj.Web;
            clientContextproj.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            clientContextproj.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
            CamlQuery query1 = new CamlQuery();
            query1.ViewXml = "<View><Query><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Text'></Value></Query></View>";

            List resourceMaster = siteproj.Lists.GetByTitle("Listname");
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection collListResourceMaster = resourceMaster.GetItems(query1);
            clientContextproj.Load(collListResourceMaster);
            clientContextproj.ExecuteQuery();

            Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = ((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet);
            bool flag = true;
            int counter = 2;
            while (flag)
            {
                string columnHeader = "A" + counter.ToString();
                Excel.Range row = activeWorksheet.get_Range(columnHeader);
                if (row.Value2 != null)
                {
                    if (collListResourceMaster.Count != 0)
                    {
                        foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem targetListItemProj in collListResourceMaster)
                        {
                            var currentResourceId = targetListItemProj["EmployeeCode"];
                            if (currentResourceId != null && currentResourceId.Equals(Convert.ToString(row.Value2)))
                            {
                                Excel.Range Exprow = activeWorksheet.get_Range("C" + counter.ToString());
                                string ValueTotal = Convert.ToString(Exprow.Value2);
                                string[] beforeExp = ValueTotal.Split('.');
                                int totalMonth = Convert.ToInt32(beforeExp[0]) * 12;
                                if (beforeExp.Count() > 1)
                                {
                                    totalMonth += Convert.ToInt32(beforeExp[1]);
                                }

                                targetListItemProj["FieldToUpdate"] = totalMonth;
                                targetListItemProj.Update();
                                clientContextproj.ExecuteQuery();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        counter += 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

This code updates columns which records have same EmployeeCode in List and in Excel.
This will update until record found in excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Const SHAREPOINT_SITE = "-----Sharepoiny Site Name-----"
Public Const SHAREPOINT_LIST = "-----Sharpeoint List Name-----"
Public Const SHAREPOINT_VIEW = "{328CC815-1952-46A8-BG8B-EE4456AF13E8}"
```

These should be declared and call in the array in the `ImportSharepoint` function as,

```
Sub ImportSharepointList()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim src(2) As Variant
    Dim iz As Integer

    '--- check if config sheet is available
    For iz = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(iz).Name = LIST_SHEETNAME Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Sheets(iz).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = LIST_SHEETNAME


    Set ws = Worksheets(LIST_SHEETNAME)
    src(0) = SHAREPOINT_SITE & "/_vti_bin"
    src(1) = SHAREPOINT_LIST
    src(2) = SHAREPOINT_VIEW
```

If you correct this. This error won't occur. It will proceed to the further steps.

Answer (score 0):

Open in datasheet view , delete the existing columns and paste the new ones. It takes a while for large data but still you can avoid coding . Make sure you match the columns as attachment is the first field and you will have to exclude.

Comment: also this works only in IE not in chrome.(tested on chrome v65)

Answer (score 0):

Please use [this tool](https://o365code.blogspot.com/2021/06/export-import-from-excel-file-in.html) to insert new records & update existing records from excel to any list.

https://o365code.blogspot.com/2021/06/export-import-from-excel-file-in.html

Thanks,
Gaurav Goyal