# Import Excel Sheet and append items to SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, excel, import, spreadsheet

I have Excel sheet and existing SharePoint list (Import spredsheet app) on my SharePoint server.

We need to append the data from the new excel sheets to the existing lists items of the SharePoint list.

How should I go about creating a solution for this?

Let's say I have 100 records in one excel file. I have imported that file to spredsheet app. It works fine for first time. Now I have 100 records in that list. Now user has added 10 more records in that excel sheet. That 10 records I have to appends to the list which is created very first time.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/34433/8642

Comment: @MdMazzotti, if you feel this is a duplicate you should use the "close" button to start a vote about marking this as a duplicate

Comment: @RobertLindgren I tried it, but apparently you cannot cast a close vote on a bounty question

Comment: @MdMazzotti, ah sorry, though your question was before the bounty!

Comment: Removed bounty (which refunded your points) and closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used OpenXml in a similar solution.
This can help you:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1fda82c4-a1ab-420a-86ad-682a1d6d33cb/openxml-read-excel-file
After you read the data, the adding is easy.

If you need further assistance please let me know.