# Best approach for updating a list - one way from Excel

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-server

In general, I am looking for a scenario in which a SharePoint (SP) list takes the updates from an Excel table.  It would be one-way from the Excel table to the SP list with the hope that a change in the Excel table would be reflected in the linked SP list dynamically.

There are 2 lists in play.

The sink list is what I need to take updates directly from the Excel table.

The VPMO list has a total of 6 columns – VPMO, Project Name, Client Priority, Area, Tower/VP, Status

One (1) column (VPMO) is the lookup to a cell within the VPMO list to sink list and two (2) columns (Project Name & Client Priority) are pulled from the sink list based on the lookup and three (3) columns (Area, Tower/VP & Status) are what I add for the total of 6.

I want to keep my information (Area, Tower/VP & Status) unchanged within the VPMO list even when the information from the sink list via the Excel table that is within the VPMO list from the sink list changes.

Example
So Project Name & Client Priority are updated within the Excel table.

I want the update to exist within the VPMO list for Project Name & Client Priority the without anything else changing.

Answer (score 0):

their are couple of ways.

SharePoint List Synchronizer is a tool created by SoftFluent to restore automatically the two-way synchronization feature between Excel and SharePoint lists.
http://www.softfluent.com/products/sharepoint-list-synchronizer

Also have a look on this answer from previous posts.

[Update Sharepoint list using excel](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34433/update-sharepoint-list-using-excel)

or

http://www.ehow.com/how_7374053_update-sharepoint-list-excel.html