# Update SharePoint from excel

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, excel, soap

Okay, so I know this question has been asked before. I have read and researched the answers. I have small amount data that needs updating. This is not adding or subtracting records, but updating fields in existing records. So , it's down to VBA with SOAP or ADO ( just a front end developer, no powershell server side programming). Or am I missing something ? Just want to make sure.

This will only be done once a month, 25 records out of 2500.

PS yes, the changes could be done manually, but they want a programatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **WSSandExcel** (SynchorinizeWSSandExcel.xlam) Add-in from Excel introduced to achieve this requirement.

Reference: [Publishing and Synchronizing Excel tables to SharePoint 2013/2016/Online Lists using Excel Add-in.](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/publishing-and-synchronizing-excel-tables-to-sharepoint-lists-excel-add-in/)

The `UpdateChanges` method in VBA is deprecated starting from *Microsoft Office Excel 2007*, which makes updating (not adding or deleting) existing records in SharePoint list unavailable.

See another post with discussion here:
[Update Sharepoint list using excel](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34433/update-sharepoint-list-using-excel/34460)

Comment: I would love to use that. Unfortunately, while we are on SharePoint 2010, we are on Excel 2016, which has been reorted not to work anymore. Also, the excel file has other vba code in it, and it never worked with a .macro enable file.  Thanks for the information about update changes.

Comment: @Dominica No problem.